# ASP.NET MVC invalid JSON, Custom Request Validating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and some of the actions are used for APIs and use JSON data. They are designed to be used with our hardware devices. Devices due to some bugs or else sometimes are sending corrupted invalid JSON. ASP.NET validates requests and respond with 500 error. Which i want to replace to 400 response.

The question is how to replace this validation check just for some actions, or whole solution, without disabling request validation for whole application.

At the moment i'm checking the error on the Application_Error, it works well, but i don't like it.

I would like to build some kind of action filter, but it seems that the request validation happens before it goes to action.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` binds the model first, before action filters.  One option may be to create a custom model binder that throws a custom exception that can be handled by a `[HandleError]` attribute which in turn returns a 400 response

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke, i thought about model binder. The case is i would like to use different models across different actions. And at the same time don't use this behavior by default across whole application.

Comment: You can specify a custom model binder for just specific action methods or model classes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tried your suggestion, it seems that the request validation happens before the model binding

Comment: [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has numerous methods you can override including [OnPropertyValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.onpropertyvalidating(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Correct me if i'm wrong, but in order to use OnPropertyValidating the JSON already has to be correct and valid, so the validation of the whole JSON in request's body has been done prior to OnPropertyValidating?

Comment: `OnPropertyValidating` occurs before any binding takes place so I think this should work, but I haven't tried it with JSON data so I'm not entirely sure